# Full examples of modulating chord sequences

Tags: modulation

I understand much of the theory of modulation, but I want examples to model. Most of the articles I can find show excerpts of songs or particular modulations, but not the progressions for whole songs, including how to get back to the original key if that is done.

In my youth I made the mistake of trying to learn lead guitar by applying the theory of which scales to use over which chords, rather than focusing more on examples of great solos. In studying modulation I don't want to make the same mistake - I want to expose myself to some great examples of modulation in the form of written chord progressions rather than getting lost in the theory.

Can anyone anyone please either provide me with some full chord sequences which include modulation, or point me to where I can find some?

Comment: The way to do what you're trying to do is to take as a starting point the excerpts you find and then do your own analysis of the piece as a whole.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because finding examples of songs including examples displaying an musical concept are off-topic.